# How can I make joblib works with executable files (.exe)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, joblib

I developed a program in python to organize data that comes from xlsx and csv and convert it to csv.
To accelerate the program, I am using joblib to do parallel processing. The program is working fine when I run on the console, but it doesn't work when I generate an executable using pyinstaller. When I run it, nothing appears on the terminal.

The main code:

```
import Conv
from os import getcwd
from time import time
from Df_2_csv import createFolder
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

#Getting the initial time
t0=time()

path=(getcwd()).replace("\\","/")
    
#Creating a folder "Csv" if it doesn't exist
newPath=createFolder(path)

#Getting all files of each type
all_xlsx= Conv.getAllOfType(path,".xlsx")
all_csv= Conv.getAllOfType(path,".csv")

#Getting the lenght of the lists
len_all=Conv.len_all(all_xlsx,all_csv)

#Run along xlsx files
Result=Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(Conv.conv_xlsx)(
    fileName,path,newPath,t0,index,len_all) for index,fileName in enumerate(all_xlsx))

#Run along csv files
Result=Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(Conv.conv_csv)(
    fileName,path,newPath,t0,index,len_all) for index,fileName in enumerate(all_csv,start=len(all_xlsx)))
```

I generated the executable using:

pyinstaller --onefile Main.py